# MYSQL, can't compare(equalize) two values

Tags: php, mysql, compare

my problem is very strange I think. I'm trying to use the following sql code:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 'roman' GROUP by `name`
```

and it returns me a null value, I'm sure the code is correct because it works with other tables. I've noticed that if I go to the table, remove the `id` value and then type it manually again, it works just fine (even tho the rest of the values look the same). My table has been imported from csv file, but I'm sure that I don't have any spaces/letters/wrong chars etc at the end of lines (even checked that with HexEdit). For example if I use:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `id` LIKE 'roman%' GROUP by `name`
```

then it works, so it appears that there's something wrong with the id values somehow. I've tried to change charset too.

Comment: could you show outputs of `SELECT id, name WHERE 'id' LIKE 'roman%' GROUP by 'name'` ? and where is your `FROM table_name` ? :-)

Comment: about the FROM, forgot to write it here but it is in the code :) I can't use LIKE  because I have some other ids similar to this one, roman_tech, roman_skills etc

Comment: To be absolutely certain, does the length of the field appear to be correct? I.e. does this return a column of value `5`? `select length(id) from ... where id like 'roman%';`

Comment: could you reset value in your table? just copy-past `roman` into the table? I am pretty sure there is some wrong value with hidden special chars, so try to place good one and query again

Comment: looks like the hex returns 6 values instead of 5
726F6D616E and 726F6D616E0D

Comment: maybe there's a function to clear tables from unnecessary characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that there is a non-printable character stored in the column, likely a carriage return, tab, or line feed.

To find out, try getting a hex representation of the value stored, and a byte length.

```
SELECT HEX('roman')
     , LENGTH('roman')
     , HEX(t.id)
     , LENGTH(t.id)
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.id <> 'roman'
   AND t.id LIKE 'roman%'
```

(It's possible that there's a characterset conversion going on. The same query above will reveal some details.)

---

There's a carriage return character, decimal value 13, on the end of the value stored.  Compare to:

```
SELECT HEX('roman\r') 

HEX('roman\r')  
----------------
726F6D616E0D
          ^^
```

To remove ALL occurrences of the carriage return characters from the `id` column (not just a trailing one), you can use the `REPLACE` function.

```
SELECT HEX(REPLACE('ro\rman\r','\r',''))

HEX(REPLACE('ro\rman\r','\r',''))  
-----------------------------------
726F6D616E
```

in an UPDATE statement, e.g.

```
UPDATE mytable SET id = REPLACE(id,'\r','')
```

---

If `id` is the last field in the .csv file, it's likely that the file had lines ended DOS style, with carriage return and line feed; and the process that read the input file stripped off the line feed only, and left the carriage return as part of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was caused by csv import, all values from last column have an extra line break symbol. I've tried the following code:

SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `id` LIKE 'roman**_**' GROUP by `name`

so it will "skip" the last char and still not select my other values like: roman_string roman_string2 etc. Maybe it's not the best solution but it's better than spending a lot of time rebuilding csv import script :) Thanks